# pass a javascript form object to remote CFC

Tags: coldfusion

I have 2 files: test.cfc and test.cfm. When I click the submit button in `test.cfm`, I am getting the following error:

> "error: Object doesn't support this property of method".

I know it has something to do with the form reference inside the `passForm` function. But after googling for hours I am still unable to resolve the error. Any advice?

**test.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="getForm"  returntype="String" access="remote">
        <cfargument name="theForm" type="struct">

    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

**test.cfm**

```
<cfajaxproxy cfc="ajaxFunc.test" jsclassname="testCFC">
<script>
    function passForm(theForm)
    {
        try
        {
            var e = new testCFC();
            message = e.getForm(theForm);
            ColdFusion.navigate('', 'myDiv');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the `serializeJSON()` and `deserializeJSON()` functions in ColdFusion?

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_s_03.html

Also, have a look at the following thread, which may be of help to you.

[How to pass STRUCT - OR - JSON to Coldfusion CFC Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489557/how-to-pass-struct-or-json-to-coldfusion-cfc-method)

Hope that helps.
Mikey.